# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast

Tags: android, eclipse

```
12-01 00:36:28.058: E/AndroidRuntime(5062): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

I am getting above error if anyone knows then tell me ...i shall very thankful

---

Java:

```
Log.d("Textra", title); 
Log.d("Dextra", des); 
EditText t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.t); 
EditText d=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.des); 
t.setText(title); 
d.setText(des);
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/t" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/des" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text=""/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The error is simple, but please post your relevant Java code, XML code, and all of the LogCat errors so we can where it is happening.

Comment: java code:     Log.d("Textra", title);
       Log.d("Dextra", des);
      EditText t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.t);
         EditText d=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.des);
         t.setText(title);
         d.setText(des);

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/des"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: Use "[edit]" to add this information to your question in the appropirate format.

Answer (score 46):

Delete R.java
Clean project 
Save files
Build & Run

Comment: Ugh, thanks, that's usually my default.  Stuff like this drives me batty.

Comment: This is simple and superb answer saved my life

Comment: I was beginning to lose the will to live. Thanks for restoring my faith in Android development!

Comment: Simply cleaning the project worked for me, but I +1 this anyways.

Answer (score 6):

```xml
<TextView android:id="@+id/t" ... /> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/des" ... />
```

```java
EditText t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.t);
EditText d=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.des);
```

Do you want TextViews or EditTexts?

Either change the XML to use EditTexts or the Java to use TextViews...

Comment: Oh my God...Big blooper.   Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

I could solve it by just cleaning the project with project/clean.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a cleanup issue then it can throw any casting error.I got this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

In eclipse, Just go to Project > Clean & Select your project to clean it.

Answer (score 0):

You use textview in xml, but in the activity you try to 
EditText t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.t) - not correct;
use
TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

or change in xml TextView to EditText