# android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText 5

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, android-activity

I have an error on my android program that I doesn't understand, I have check the syntax of the XML file but I didn't see any mistake.

Here

My errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twitter/com.example.twitter.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
at com.example.twitter.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:48)
```

Here is the line of the error:

```
lblName         = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
```

My activity:

```
    package com.example.twitter;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager(); // Alert Dialog Manager
    RefreshManager refresh = new RefreshManager(); // Refresh Manager
    SessionManager session; // Session Manager Class
    private UsersDAO dao; // Init Posts DAO
    private ListAdapter PostAdapter;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private EditText lblName, lblUsername, lblDescription, lblEmail, lblLocalisation, lblWebsite;

    // Buttons
    Button validSignup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account);

        dao = new UsersDAO(this); // On se connecte a la BDD
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()); // Session class instance

        lblName         = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        lblUsername     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        lblDescription  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
        lblEmail        = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        lblLocalisation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_localisation);
        lblWebsite      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_website);

        session.checkLogin();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        lblName.setText(user.get(SessionManager.NAME));
        lblUsername.setText(user.get(SessionManager.USERNAME));
        lblDescription.setText(user.get(SessionManager.DESCRIPTION));
        lblEmail.setText(user.get(SessionManager.EMAIL));
        lblLocalisation.setText(user.get(SessionManager.LOCALISATION));
        lblWebsite.setText(user.get(SessionManager.WEBSITE));

        // Login button
        validSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valid_setting);

        // Login button click event
        validSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Get username, password from EditText
                String upd_name         = lblName.getText().toString();
                String upd_username     = lblUsername.getText().toString();
                String upd_description  = lblDescription.getText().toString();
                String upd_email        = lblEmail.getText().toString();
                String upd_localisation = lblLocalisation.getText().toString();
                String upd_website      = lblWebsite.getText().toString();

                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String d = sdf.format(new Date());
                Integer id_user = 2;

                dao.update(id_user, upd_username, upd_email, upd_name, upd_description, upd_website, upd_localisation, d);

                // Check if username, password is filled                
                if( upd_name.trim().length() > 0 
                        && upd_username.trim().length() > 0 
                        && upd_description.trim().length() > 0 
                        && upd_email.trim().length() > 0 
                        && upd_localisation.trim().length() > 0
                        && upd_website.trim().length() > 0 ){

                    // For testing puspose username, password is checked with sample data
                    // get the current date
                    //dao = new UsersDAO(getApplicationContext());

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String d = sdf.format(new Date());

                    System.out.println("time "+d);
                    Integer id_user = 2;

                    dao.update(id_user, upd_username, upd_email, upd_name, upd_description, upd_website, upd_localisation, d);

                }else{
                    // user didn't entered username or password
                    // Show alert asking him to enter the details
                    alert.showAlertDialog(SettingsActivity.this, "Update settings fail..", "You must fill all the fields", false);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                refresh.data(getApplicationContext(), true);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

XML file

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_name" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_x="0dp" 
        android:layout_y="80dp" 
        android:hint="Nom et prénom" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/valid_setting"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="397dp"
        android:text="Mettre à jour" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lab_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:text="Nom d utilisateur"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nom d&apos;utilisateur" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="60dp"
        android:text="Nom complet"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="2dp"
        android:layout_y="120dp"
        android:text="Adresse Email"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="140dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Adresse Email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="180dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="200dp" 
        android:hint="Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="240dp"
        android:text="URL du site"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="260dp" 
        android:hint="URL du site" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="300dp"
        android:text="Localisation"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_localisation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="320dp" 
        android:hint="Localisation" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="24dp"
        android:layout_y="358dp"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project? Project >> Clean...

Comment: you sure you are using the right layout post your R.layout.account

Comment: please check [here][1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674627/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674627/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem: I have not updated the XML view on my activity :

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.account);
```

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting your R.java file. It will be regenerated. Sometimes when you move items inside the xml it seems to lose the reference so it still thinks there's a TextView there.

Comment: Just needed to run a clean in Android Studio - resolved the issue right away.